# Two different sharepoint sites but the documents in the recent document feed appear the same documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, documentation

Hi I have created two sharepoint sites for my work . The problem is that when I go to the "recent documents" section of the one website , it appears the recent documents shared in the other site. Has anyone anyone any idea what is going wrong ?

---

Hi again many thanks for the answer .So if I understand well the users of the one will be able to see what the users of the other are uploading except if they are common users on both sites. Right ?

Comment: In which web part are you seeing the documents from another site?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the **[Recent Documents web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-recent-documents-web-part-8aa8c0f2-d2e3-43f9-90f5-fd6ddf0669c3)** on the page, it is normal to display the same documents on different SharePoint sites.

Because the **Recent Documents web part** displays recently modified or accessed documents from **all of the SharePoint sites + OneDrive account** for the user who is logged in.

[image]